# How to remove blank spaces 2 digit integers make in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, console, 2d

I'm trying to make a simple 12x12 times table for my console application.

However when I input my double for loops, as soon as it reaches a two digit value, it leaves a space behind.

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-f9aeH2PaXdc/VNbETAJkKxI/AAAAAAAAAIs/dNm3stirQoM/w675-h341-no/help.png

(Link to what it looks like)

I need to find a way to straighten the table out to this 
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2iO0PAwElZA/VNbEPv8gtnI/AAAAAAAAAIk/66ofURW5Yq8/w676-h345-no/Picture1.png

Here is also the following code:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim table(12, 12) As Integer

    For i = 1 To 12
        Console.Write("" & i & " ")
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("")

    For i = 1 To 12
        For j = 1 To 12
            table(i, j) = i * j
        Next
    Next

    For i = 1 To 12
        Console.Write(i & "")
        Console.Write(" ")
        For j = 1 To 12
            Console.Write(" |" & table(i, j) & "")
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

If anybody could find a solution to this I would be grateful

Comment: notice how some entries are longer than others (`"1"` vs `"12"`)?  It means you need to pad  each column based on the max length of the longest item in that column *or* pad them all to a max length/width vs adding the same number of spaces for all of them

Comment: How exactly do you write that in code? (Sorry new here)